# Order in draggable

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This example : https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

```
<ul id="sortable" ng-repeat="x in getTime(3)">
  <li class="ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
   Item {{$index}} and order : ¿ {{order}} ?
  </li>
</ul>
```

This generate :

```
<li> item 1 and order 1 </li>
<li> item 2 and order 2 </li>
<li> item 3 and order 3 </li>
```

But if i change the third `<li>` at first, i would  Item 3 and order 1, i need update order in `<li>` all

```
<li> item 3 and order 1 </li>
<li> item 1 and order 2 </li>
<li> item 2 and order 3 </li>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do not understand what you're asking.  "If I change the third <li> at first".  Please explain your question better.

Comment: @Rani Radcliff i update post

Answer (score 0):

you need to give set track by index in your ng-reapeat feild. if you add following code and try again.

```
<ul id="sortable" ng-repeat="x in listValue track by $index"">
  <li class="ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
   Item {{$index}} and order : ¿ {{order}} ?
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem isn't index, i need update the "order" value when i move the "li" of posicion

Comment: @sirdaiz, try this one      $scope.listValue = [];

frst u need to get copy of changeable item. Then,
var 1stObj = listValue[1]
var 3rdObj = listValue[3]

While you update, when use 

$scope.listValue.splice(index3, 1, 1stObj);
$scope.listValue.splice(index1, 1, 3rdObj);

Comment: if i have 100 '<li>' i cant declared var 1rdObj  ... var 100rdObj

Comment: What is in your getTime function?  I'm trying to help you, but it is difficult given the limited amount of code you've provided.  I tried to test your code in a Plunker can't seem to get the "sortable" to even work with ng-repeat.  I'm unfamiliar with JQuery UI.  If you can get these two working together, I could help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angular-UI Sortable with JQuery UI
In your HTML:

```
<ul class="list" ng-model="table1" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="p in table1">{{ p.name }} and order {{p.order}}</li>
</ul>
```

In your Controller:

```
 $scope.table1 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        order: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        order: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Data3',
        order: 3
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Data4',
        order: 4
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Data5',
        order: 5
    }
];
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        for (var index in $scope.table1) {
            $scope.table1[index].order = Number(index) + 1;

        }


    }
};
```

You can get Sortable.js [Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/).  And here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ymfh7L?p=preview) that I believe achieves what you want.  Hope this helped.  Good luck!

Comment: I like this, let me try it later and I'll tell you, thanks